# MachineKey.Protect() equivalent in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the equivalent (if there is one) of `MachineKey.Protect()` and `MachineKey.Unprotect()` in ASP.NET Core

Comment: the new dataprotection api is what you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/

Comment: @JoeAudette that answers my question. Why don't you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the new dataprotection api is what you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/

Comment: Getting started quick-link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection

Answer (score 1):

you can use this nuget package from below url
 https://www.nuget.org/packages/SFSecurity/1.0.0#

or directly install by command "Install-Package SFSecurity -Version 1.0.0"